# “Ich möchte bitte ein Glas Wasser” – should I also include “trinken” in this phrase?

Tags: phrase

I’ve noticed that in some occasions

> Ich möchte bitte ein Glas Wasser.

is not enough if want I want to say something like

> I’d like to drink a glass of water, please.

It is correct to also include *trinken* here or should I stick with the simple form, without *trinken*? And if yes, which of the following two forms is accepted?

> Ich möchte **trinken** bitte ein Glas Wasser.
>   Ich möchte bitte ein Glas Wasser **trinken**.

Comment: This is wrong: _Ich möchte trinken bitte ein Glas Wasser_

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that “Ich möchte bitte ein Glas Wasser.” was not enough?

Comment: Wheter adding 'trinken' is correct depends on the context occasion which you didn't provide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a glass of water, don't add "trinken". It sounds very unusual (like you want to drink the glass).

> Ich möchte bitte ein Glas Wasser.

Is totally acceptable. Stick with that. One alternative, which sounds a bit more polite and also features the verb you seem to desire, is:

> Könnte ich bitte ein Glas Wasser **haben**?

Comment: What about the case where I want to say "I would like to bring me a glass of water". Should I add _bringen_ in one of the two forms I put in my question?

Comment: Well, the sentence looks a bit wonky, but if you ask someone to bring you a glass of water, you add 'bringen'. Here is an example: "Können sie mir ein Glas Wasser bringen?".

Comment: I have to disagree here. "Ich möchte ein Glas Wasser trinken." does not sound unusual at all to me (native speaker from Southern Germany), and no-one would have the idea that "ein Glas Wasser trinken", "eine Flasche Wasser trinken", etc., mean that you actually want to drink the *container* rather than its *content*. This becomes clear when you look at other sentences, where the action of drinking rather than the desire to do so is in the focus - "Ich trinke jetzt ein Glas Wasser.", "Wir haben eine Tasse Kaffee getrunken.", etc. What verb would you use there instead of *trinken*?

Comment: In regards to asking someone if you could have a glass of water, I wouldn't use 'trinken' (or any other substitute) because it's superfluous in this sentence. In the other sentences you mentioned, 'trinken' describes the action you are/were doing.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowledge of the context, this is difficult to answer.

1. Asking to have/get a glass of water (e.g. from a server): Don't add `trinken` as it is of no concern to the server what you're planning to do with the glas of water.

   > Ich möchte bitte ein Glas Wasser (haben).
2. Informing somebody else, that you are interrupting your work/a discussion in order to drink a glass of water: Add `trinken` as it would otherwise seem to be case 1.

   > Ich möchte ein Glas Wasser trinken. [Danach bin ich wieder für Sie da.]